# Как включить анимацию при появление блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как запустить анимацию во время появление блока?

сейчас анимация запускается во время загрузки страницы, а нужно чтобы запускалась, когда пользователь дойдёт до конца страницы.

```css
.sms {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
 .clear {
     clear: both;
}
 .from-me {
     position: relative;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     color: white;
     background: #0b93f6;
     border-radius: 25px;
     float: right;
}
 .from-me:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
     bottom: -2px;
     right: -7px;
     height: 20px;
     border-right: 20px solid #0b93f6;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
     -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
}
 .from-me:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     bottom: -2px;
     right: -56px;
     width: 26px;
     height: 20px;
     background: white;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}
 
 @keyframes loud {
     20% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     25% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     30% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     35% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     40% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     45% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     50% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     60% {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg) scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
     to {
         transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    }
}
 .loud {
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     transform-origin: center center;
     animation-name: loud;
}
 

.content {
  widht: 100%;
  height: 500px
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>скролить вниз</h1>
<div class="content"></div>

<section class="sms">
  <div class="from-me loud">
    <p>Hey there! What's up?!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<h1>скролить вниз</h1>
<div class="content"></div>

<section class="sms">
  <div class="from-me">
    <p>Hey there! What's up?!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

</section>
```

JS

```
  let sms = document.querySelector('.from-me');
    
    function show_onscroll() {
     
        let wt = window.scrollY;
        let wh = document.body.clientHeight;
        let eh = sms.offsetHeight;
        let et = sms.offsetTop;
    
        if (wt+wh > et+eh*0.4)
        return true;
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        
      if (show_onscroll())
      sms.classList.add("loud");
    
    });
```

С этим коэфициентом можно играться, чтобы раньше или позже анимация срабатывала.

```
(wt+wh > et+eh*0.4)
```